# Where can I find an explained list of emoji (emoticons) used in iOS?

Tags: macos, ios, unicode, emoji

Where can I find an explained list of  emoji (emoticons) used in iOS for use on Mac OS X?

Some of them are not quite clear and I would like to see their base meaning (I know that you are free to use them, still as the glyphs they should have an Unicode name).

Comment: For anyone now looking for a much better resource that's available on more than just Macs and shows images of the glyphs rendered on several different platforms/environments, check it out here: http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, in **System Preferences**, under the **Keyboard** tab of the **Keyboard** Preference Pane, be sure *Show Keyboard and Character Viewers in menu bar* is checked.
[image]

Then, from the Keyboard menu in the menu bar, select **Show Character Viewer**. In the Character viewer pane, select Emoji. When you select an Emoji, on the right side of the pane, you get a large graphic of the Emoji and a text explanation of the shape.
[image]

Comment: This is also reachable in most programs under Edit > Special Characters…

Answer (score 8):

There's also a [list on my web site](http://grumdrig.com/emoji-list/), that I just made. The list is viewable using a browser with emoji font support; this includes Safari.

Comment: I just read your list and was about to post a link to it here as an answer — only to find that you, the person who created it, already posted here! Great work on the list. Have an upvote.

Comment: Funny. This page was the best resource I found when looking for this information myself, so now hopefully it's better.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the list!!!!! Great reference; now I know what I'm saying :)

Comment: This works fine on Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 as well. Awesome list. Great work!

Answer (score 4):

When you're in iOS, you can also turn on VoiceOver and it'll read the names of the Emoji as you move around the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a series of tables at [w:Emoji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji). Additionally, they also organize it by what platform supports what character as well.