# Where are emojis stored on Macs?

Tags: macos, emoji

I saw the iPhone emoji and I want to get a high quality image of it to turn into the space grey color, but I can't find an image on the Internet. Does anyone know where the image file for the emoji is stored?

I am using OS X Yosemite.

Thanks.

Comment: Do the answers to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52557/where-can-i-find-an-explained-list-of-emoji-emoticons-used-in-ios?rq=1 help? If not, are you looking for one specific emoji (which one) or for all?

Comment: I'm looking for where all of the image files for the emojis are stored on my hard drive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Emojis are handled like any other fonts, the corresponding font file is stored in `/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Color Emoji.ttc`. So there are no images per se which you could reuse (even ignoring any potential copyright problems).

Three options on how to get emoji images (without programming a little tool to parse the font file directly):

- use the Character Viewer as described in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/52558/9058) and a screen grabber to get an image from the emoji you are interested in
- use Font Book to look at the characters/glyphs available in "Apple Color Emoji"
- use Google Image Search to find bigger image file representing the emoji you need

Comment: This answer may shed light on how to turn emoji into images. Have not yet tested myself. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/127640